# CoreData automatic migrations in static library

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, magicalrecord

I am currently using Magical Record to store the database on my iOS application.

I am storing the core data xcdatamodeld in a static library which is a sub project of my application.

The application can read / write to the database fine.

I have just added a property to one of my models which should trigger an automatic migration from my model versions, however this is not happening.

The following code [MagicalRecord shouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch] is returning true, so my database is being dropped and created.

Looking at Apples guides for automatic migrations adding a single property should be fine.

I'm also setting up Magical Record like this     [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];

I am wondering if because the core data .xcdatamodeld is within the sub project I have to do any additional work
for the migration to be successful

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking at the errors returned by [NSPersistentStore addPersistantStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error]

it returns cannot find model for source store.

So I did a bit of googling and found that if I added App Model Version to my .xcdatamodeld file

In my second version I added the property to the same model and the migration works.

I was under the impression that I did not need to do this however because adding a property should be
considered a lightweight migration and not require me to create a new model version.

Am I incorrect regarding this?

Comment: You will need to create a new version, and keep your old version, of the model for every collection of changes you make. If your app is still in development, you can just delete your development data store and the app will rebuild the store properly

Comment: Lightweight migration always requires model migration. Only changes not affecting database structure are allowed (like fetched properties, etc).